# How to make JavaScript code safe and secure so that API Key values cannot be open to public yet available for JavaScipt to process the code

Tags: javascript, security

```
const form = document.querySelector('.subsform');
    const submitButton = form.querySelector('input[type="button"]');
    const messageDiv = document.querySelector('#newsletter-message');

submitButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const firstName = form.querySelector('input[placeholder="First Name"]').value;
  const lastName = form.querySelector('input[placeholder="Last Name"]').value;
  const email = form.querySelector('input[type="email"]').value;
  const apiKey = form.querySelector('input[name="mailchimpAPIkey"]').getAttribute('data-api');
  const listId = form.querySelector('input[name="mailChimpListId"]').getAttribute('data-listId');
  
  console.log({ firstName, lastName, email, apiKey, listId });
  
  const url = `https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/${listId}/members/`;
  const data = {
    email_address: email,
    status: 'subscribed',
    merge_fields: {
      FNAME: firstName,
      LNAME: lastName
    }
  };
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(`apikey:${apiKey}`)}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  
  fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      messageDiv.innerHTML = `Thank you for subscribing, ${firstName}!`;
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      messageDiv.innerHTML = 'There was an error subscribing. Please try again later.';
      console.error(error);
    });
});
```

The above Javascript code processes the submit button interaction so that users can be subscribed, but it is vulnerable to security.

I do not know if there is a way to make the code safer as anyone with basic JS knowledge can grab all the hidden input tags with this code pasted in the console:

```
// Select all hidden input tags on the page
const hiddenInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"]');

// Loop through all hidden input tags and log them to the console
hiddenInputs.forEach(input => {
  console.log(input);
});
```

Comment: You simply cannot protect credentials in client-side code

Comment: Just don't. Send the data to your own backend, then submit it to mailchimp there. It don't change much since you will be just proxying the request, but your api key will not be exposed. Also you can apply some extra security like throttling.

Comment: Pretty sure the [Mailchimp API](https://mailchimp.com/en-au/help/about-api-keys/) doesn't support what you're trying to do anyway... _"Because of the potential security risks associated with exposing account API keys, Mailchimp does not support client-side implementation of our API using CORS requests or including API keys in mobile apps."_

Comment: Post is closed. Thanks everyone BTW.